# Azure DNS Forwarding

Tags: azure, redirect, dns, devops, forwarding

New to DevOps

I've been assigned the transfer of Our GoDaddy DNS to Azure I cannot find any ressource that allows me to setup DNS Forwarding in Azure
Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly straightforward:
Use either a CNAME record or an A record on GoDaddy to map a custom DNS name to App Service running on azure.

see also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/2168/how-can-i-transfer-a-domain-from-godaddy-to-azure.html